# Flutter iOS run error : Could not parse callback cache, aborting restore

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, dart

I have created a flutter project. when run my app in iOS simulator then I am facing this error.
It shows error as "[VERBOSE0:callback_cache.cc(133)] Could not parse callback cache, aborting restore" while running on Xcode.

Comment: i'm facing same issue..whats the solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I found [this thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22787) on the Flutter repository. (Check the last comment) Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. This is useful recommendation

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue after accidentally left `Main Interface` in `Deployment Info` in `Runner.xcodeproj` empty. And my solution is to get this back into `Main.storyboard`.

Comment: dude can you please add more details?some of us are noobs in xcode...